# cannot pass a subclass pointer to a function when the function need a reference to the parent pointer, why?

Tags: c++

```
class Parent{

};

class Child:
   public Parent
{

}

void Func(Parent*& param)
{

}

Child* c=new Child;

Func(c); //error
```

Comment: You're right, you can't. What's the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.

`c` is not a `Parent*`, it is a `Child*`.  To turn it into a `Parent*`, an implicit conversion is required.  This implicit conversion generates a temporary `Parent*` object (at least conceptually), and a non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary object.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the reason why:

```
struct Parent {};

struct Child: Parent { int a; };

void Func(Parent*& param) { param = new Parent(); }

int main() {
    Child* c = 0;

    Func(c); // suppose this was allowed, and passed a reference to "c".
    c->a;    // oh dear. The purpose of a type system is to prevent this.
}
```

If you can change `Func` to take `Parent *const &`, that would be OK.

Answer (score 4):

See the C++ FAQ item ["21.2 Converting Derived* → Base* works OK; why doesn't Derived** → Base** work?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/proper-inheritance.html#faq-21.2).

Note that this is the same problem as converting Derived*& to Base*&.

Cheers & hth.,